# What woods or wood materials are unsafe for use in animal cages?

Tags: safety, animals, toxicity

I want to build wooden toys/houses/things for caged pets, such as Degus, Hamsters, etc.

I'm aware that there are chemicals and glues used to make some wood products, such as MDF which make the dust created by cutting it somewhat toxic to human health.

How could I select an appropriate wood or wood material for my animal cage, considering that the animals may chew on them?  Are MDF and other plywoods safe, or do they contain toxins that may be dangerous for pets if they are ingested in small quantities?

Comment: This might be a better question to ask at [Pets.SE](http://pets.stackexchange.com/) it can vary by species.  Also green wood has issues for some species where kiln dried does not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question would truly be better served by the pets.se community rather than woodworking.  I'd suggest migrating it to pets.se or having the asker re-ask on pets.se and closing this question.

Comment: I guess this is one of those cross-topic questions that could go on either site - I assumed people who actually *make* animal furniture would more likely visit this site.

Comment: I think it does fit on either site, but the domain of knowledge (what is safe for a pet?) is probably better served by the pets community rather than here.

Comment: I voted to close this question as to broad.  In it's current format it would be to broad at Pets also.  Here is an example question for one use of wood products for one species and the answer is very long.  [What do I need to consider when buying litter for a rabbit?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2230/what-do-i-need-to-consider-when-buying-litter-for-a-rabbit)

Comment: @StampyCode hey there!  This question was undeleted because we felt the question and conversation had historical value to the context of the site.  Voting to Close doesn't actually cause the question to be deleted and shouldn't be considered a negative.  Please feel free to continue asking questions on the site!

Comment: I think this kind of question should be okay here.  Woodworking requires knowledge of the safety and appropriateness of the materials; honestly I'd expect an experienced woodworker to know more than even some vets as to what kind of woods or wood products are safe.

Comment: I've made an edit that (once reviewed) should make this a bit more clearly worded.  I don't think the question is inherently too broad; the linked pet question/answer is an interesting answer but it's much more detail than this question requires.

Comment: I've created a similar (more specific) question on the Pets.SE site as suggested ([link](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7851/is-plywood-bad-for-any-small-caged-pets)). I wonder if anyone on there will recommend the question be migrated to the Woodworking.SE site :)